# Forming vrt of 4139 ecw files?

Tags: qgis, vrt

I have 4139 ecw files of aerial photography that I would like to be able to open fairly easily and quickly in a QGIS project. I thought a virtual raster would be the way but when I have tried it comes up with the error:

[image]

I did this through Raster > Miscellaneous > Build Virtual Raster (Catalog)...

Could it be the length of the file path? Don't think it's too long.

Can you join several virtual rasters together?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time it is due to the length of the command line generated in the dialog box.

Look how the command is structured and/or rather type something like the following :

```
gdalbuildvrt my_vrt.vrt *.ecw
```

It will "pick" all the *.ecw files located in your source folder.

Comment: Ah ok. I'm not very good with writing commands. Do I need to substitute some of the wording above? I just tried copying and pasting that command but it came up with this error: ERROR 4: `*.ecw' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name. 
Warning 1: Can't open *.ecw. Skipping it

Comment: u have to ensure your are using the right locations : before `my_vrt` you must add the location of the file u want to create (u must have write permission ...) and before "*.ecw" u must add your source folder. it could be something like : `gdalbuildvrt d:\myfolder\my_vrt.vrt s:\mysourcefolder\ *.ecw`

Comment: And **yes** u have to subsitute the whole content by this command and it should be fine.

Comment: I've copied and pasted these locations and it comes up with errors saying the locations don't exist?

Comment: my example is just an example u have to adapt the paths according to your needs ... is it more clear ?

Comment: Hannah, why don't you edit your question to include the code you're using. This will help the community to debug your code, and it'll be helpful to anyone who comes to this page in the future.

Comment: Is your problem solved ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself well above. I think I understand what you're saying but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm replacing "d:\myfolder" with my  destination folder and "s:\mysourcefolder" with my source folder. i.e.  gdalbuildvrt M:\QGIS files\AP virtual rasters\my_vrt.vrt M:\??? MapInfo files\01 GIS Data Catalogue\1.2 Aerial Photography\1.2.0 Aerial Photos 2013 *.ecw

Comment: Why do you have question marks in the naming of your folders ? You should also avoid spaces. If there's any space the whole path must be put in brackets.If it still doesn't work make a test with a simplified file tree ...

Comment: I don't have question marks , I've just taken the name of the company out for privacy.

Comment: Ah ok ... u have to handle the spaces in the command line in any case

Comment: Thanks very much for all of your help! I tried the brackets. That stopped the errors mentioned above but then I got a permission error instead. As far as I'm aware though I have no restrictions.